# How do I change bullet on categories block?

Tags: block-editor

The **categories block** displays an unordered list with bullets. I want to change the `list-style` property to `none`. How do I edit `theme.json` to modify this property?

```json
"styles": {
  "blocks": {
    "core/categories": {
      "listStyle": "none"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to do this via CSS, because [Categories List](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#categories-list) only supports align, spacing (margin, padding) and typography (fontSize, lineHeight) and not list-style.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be adding a feature request and come back to post link here.

Comment: Please elaborate where you would add the CSS (style.css vs customizer).

Comment: The customizer just opens the style.css and saves your changes in that file. So it doesn't matter where you add your styles.